# Moving Object with Button - Hold Option

Tags: android, button

i'm working on a small Android Program and have a problem. I have to Buttons, set as regions, in my program and when they are touched i want them to move an object. This is working. 
The Problem ist that i want these buttons to keep the sprite moving when it is touched. At the moment it is doing the code one time when i press one of the buttons.

How can i make the buttons keep the object moving as long as the button is pressed?

Thank you!

```
    Region Rbleft = new Region(135,1585,450,1900);
    Region Rbright = new Region(630,1585,945,1900);



public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        synchronized (getHolder()){
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if(Rbleft.contains((int)x, (int)y)){
            if(xw <= getWidth() - (lore.getWidth()/2)){
                xw=xw-1;
            }   
        }           
        else if(Rbright.contains((int)x, (int)y)){
            if(xw <= getWidth() - (lore.getWidth()/2)){
                xw=xw+1;
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);}
    }
```

Comment: You can check if the button is been pressed down by checking the motion event in `onTouch` against MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN constant.

Comment: i tried this one in many different forms but i couldn't even get anything happen with OnTouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is an example that just counts instead of performing the operation you want, you can put your operation in the `doInBackground()` method. I added a touch listener onto the button instead of just using the `onTouchEvent`.

```
Button b1;
boolean flag = false;
DoWork doWork;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Log.i("TAG", "Action Down Detected");
                flag = true;
                doWork = new DoWork();
                doWork.execute();
                return true;
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                Log.i("TAG", "Action Up Detected");
                flag = false;
                doWork.cancel(false);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

class DoWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... resId) {
      while(flag) {
          synchronized (this) {
              this.sleep(100);
              count++;
          }
          Log.i("TAG", Integer.toString(count));
      }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

    private void sleep(int delay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The sleep method will give you the control you want with the speed. E.g. 1000 = 1 second delay

Comment: Does the same like the code above. The Action is executed one time, i want it to be executed every 0,1sec when the button is still pressed.

Comment: What you could is take your synchronised method and move it to its own method outside `onTouch`, then you can put a true flag in the `ACTION_DOWN` and a false flag in the `else` block. Then just perform a loop `while (flag == true){}`.

Comment: Okay, this kind of worked. But it's too fast, the object is directly on the side of the screen, is there a way to slow the while action down? maybe one move for one frame? And i believe that the while loop cant be broken, because it only reacts on the first onTouch.

Comment: You would have to use an `AsyncTask` for that, I am currently updating Android Studio, And will update my answer when it's done.

Comment: Thank you for your work but is it really so complicated to get a button with an action while holding the button? -.-

Comment: Seems so, that code is not complicated, the execute call just kicks off an `AsycTask`, plus you would probably want to do these kinds of operations asynchronously as to not make the main UI thread hang.

Comment: If you didn't want to use the `AsyncTask`, you could do your operation in the `onTouchEvent`, and check for `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){}`, however you would have to move your finger slightly to get it to trigger every time.

Comment: Yeah, i tried this one before and it didn't worked for my purpose, but based on your Code i found a solution for my problem, i changed my program a little bit so the first solution from you works now, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this following process:

```
    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

           @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (btn.isPressed()){
                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000,100) {


                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long l) {

                            btn.setEnabled(false);
                            if (!btn.isPressed()){
                                countDownTimer.cancel();
                                btn.setEnabled(true);

                            }



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            btn.setEnabled(true);

                        //do whatever you want

                        }
                    }.start();

                }


                return false;

            }
        });
```